# Random Ball Speed in P5.js

Tags: javascript, random, p5.js

I have the following code:

```
var posX1 = 0, posY1 = 100;
var speedX1 = random(1,3), speedY1 = random(1,3);

var posX2 = 0, posY2 = 200;
var speedX2 = 2, speedY2 = 0;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(640, 480);
}

function draw()
{
    // redraw the background so you blank the screen
    background(255);

    if(posX1 > width)
    {
      speedX1 = -speedX1;
    }

    // update the position based on the speed
    posX1 += speedX1;
    posY1 += speedY1;

    // draw a ball
    strokeWeight(20);
    point(posX1, posY1);

    //
    posX2 += speedX2;
    posY2 += speedY2;

    //draw a ball
    strokeWeight(20);
    point(posX2, posY2);


}
```

Its in P5. I basically want the two circles to race each other at random speeds between 1 and 3 but instead they dont even appear on the screen. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use P5.js functions before `setup()` is called.

If you run this code and look at the JavaScript console (which should always be your first step) you'll see that you're getting an error saying that `random()` is not defined. If you then Google that error, you'll get a ton of results explaining what's going on.

From [the P5.js FAQ](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup):

> ### Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before setup()?
>
> The explanation for this is a little complicated, but it has to do
>   with the way the library is setup in order to support both global and
>   instance mode. To understand what's happening, let's first look at the
>   order things happen when a page with p5 is loaded (in global mode).
>
> 1. Scripts in `<head>` are loaded.
> 2. `<body>` of HTML page loads (when this is complete, the onload event fires, which then triggers step 3).
> 3. p5 is started, all functions are added to the global namespace.
>
> So the issue is that the scripts are loaded and evaluated before p5 is
>   started, when it's not yet aware of the p5 variables. If we try to
>   call them here, they will cause an error. However, when we use p5
>   function calls inside setup() and draw() this is ok, because the
>   browser doesn't look inside functions when the scripts are first
>   loaded. This is because the setup() and draw() functions are not
>   called in the user code, they are only defined, so the stuff inside of
>   them isn't run or evaluated yet.
>
> It's not until p5 is started up that the setup() function is actually
>   run (p5 calls it for you), and at this point, the p5 functions exist
>   in the global namespace.

In other words, you have to **define** your variables at the top of your sketch, but only **assign** them inside the `setup()` function:

```
var speedX1;
var speedY1;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(640, 480);

    speedX1 = random(1,3);
    speedY1 = random(1,3);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just tried that and it works fine. I didn't realise random had to be in setup but do now!